# SQL OLAP Cube and dimension

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, olap-cube, cube-dimension

In a windows Server 2008, using SQL server 2005, Visual Studio and SQL Server Analysis Services i created an OLAP Cube.

The scenario is a typical store with sell products, customer and agents.

The cube is made by a fact table tblVendite (sell data) and dimensions based on sql views.

**NOTE**: *I tried embed the screenshot here but they will resized and will not clear so i posted them in a safe site to view it:*

[SCREENSHOT: stucture of the cube](http://www.gaivi.it/adk/cube.jpg)

- FACT TABLE tblVendite (sell) > **PK: CdArticolo** (IDProduct)
- DIMENSION  Prodotti (produtcs)
- DIMENSION  Calendario (calendar)
- DIMENSION  Agenti (agents)
- DIMENSION  Clienti (customer)

Browsing the cube with basic filters as calendar, customer/agent, products, brand ... all work fine

Now i need to provide a new feature as:
**Comparing the "top sell brand" of all company with the sell of each agent to see how he sell those brand**

So i did a new table and the related view: `vwMarcheOrd` (top sell brand)

The table *top sell brand* is pre-populated by a `sp` and contain 1 record for each brand (`CdMarca` - `Position` - `Description`  order by Position)

**NOTE**: from `vwMarcheOrd` i cant have direct link to the fact table because the PK is `CdMarca` and it's not present so i need to "bridge" the view Products by `CdMarca` and get the `CdArticolo` to link the fact table

Dimension and the attributes for `Brand` and `Top Brand`:

[SCREENSHOT: cube dimension](http://www.gaivi.it/adk/dimension.jpg)

**BROWSE THE CUBE AND THE PROBLEM**

Adding the dimension `Brand`(1) to the row fields the result is correct but if i add the `Top Brand`(2) **is incorrect and many brand are missing** (but they exist)

[SCREENSHOT: browse Top Brand](http://www.gaivi.it/adk/querybrand.jpg)

So my questions are 2:

1. What i missing or wrong or misunderstand with the `Top Brand` Dimension ?
2. `How i can display all records` of Top Brand in the row fields even if the agent      didnt sell any item of that brand (blank row) ?

*p.s. i tried also make a dimension based only with vMarcheOrd and then create a Referenced Relationship with the Product table to bridge CdMarca > CdArticolo > Fact Table but the result are the same*

Thanks in advance who can really help me to solve this problem that block me since many days

Comment: what is the join between the new view vwMarcheOrd and the products view? What is a top brand and how do you know it is a top brand? Your images are not readable.

Comment: @Ali_Abadani i've updated the information to answer your questions

Comment: Ali's answer below is possibly correct, but it's very unclear from your description what a "top brand" actually is. A product can only be "top" (most units sold, most revenue, most margin) over a defined period of time, so how do you handle top brand for January vs. top brand for the whole year? Or is this not relevant in your scenario?

Comment: the problem has been solved (look the Ali_Abadani) comment, so i wanna say thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, it looks like the top brand could change over time. This means that you would need to somehow track that over time. In my opnion, the easiest way to do that would be to add the TopBrandKey to the fact table and join the top brand dimension directly to the fact table. This way the time tracking is done for you in the fact table. As new records come in, you would look up the key for the top brand and add that to the fact table. I don't think the way you have it would work because the product which was sold would not have the brand which is the top brand (those are two different things).

Comment: Thanks for your clarification but i cant have the TopBrandKey in the fact table, in this scenario i can only read the data and dont change anything because others DataWareHouse are used.
And the TopBrandKey is "relationship referenced" by the bridge vProdotti as explained above.
Btw i found the problem few minutes ago and was that table (the top brand) that due a porting from SQL 2000 had incorrect data inside. So after rebuild the table and re-process the cube, all work fine finally.

Answer (score 0):

ciao luka :)

it seems to me that you don't have the proper attribute relationship between the attributes on your cube.

I see you are using BIDS 2005, which I'm not very familiar with it (it would be easier to help on 2008), but what you have to do is set the relations between Prodoti -> Brand -> top brand

you can do that by those + signs on the attributes bellow the dimension name.